# SQL query comparing with if's statement for previous and current ID's

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two CTEs one is for current period and the other is previous period. I want to create an IF's statement that compares the current Finding ID to the previous Finding ID and if they don't match, I want it to be in the category of "Transfer Out". However, I am having an error creating the if's statement. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

---

```
;with transfer_current_mc as 
    (
        --Current
        select snapshot_dt, finding_id, mc_clean_name, mc_1_down_clean_name, 'current' as current_col from audit.archer_findings_snapshot 
        where snapshot_dt = @current_snapshot and snapshot_time_granularity= @Snapshot
    ),
transfer_previous_mc as
    (
        --Previous
        select snapshot_dt, finding_id, mc_clean_name, mc_1_down_clean_name,'previous' as previous_col from audit.archer_findings_snapshot 
        where snapshot_dt = @previous_snapshot and snapshot_time_granularity = @Snapshot
    )
```

---

```
select if a.finding_id <> b.finding_id else 'Transfer Out' end 
from transfer_current_mc a inner join transfer_previous_mc b on a.finding_id = b.finding_id
```

Comment: I believe you need a `CASE` statement within your `SELECT` clause when doing these types of operations.

Comment: What is the error message

Comment: It just says:
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'if'.
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'else'. Maybe I'm not doing my if statement correctly.

Comment: `if a.finding_id <> b.finding_id else 'Transfer Out' end` is not valid sql server syntax..  like Anthony said, look into CASE

Comment: There also is the possibility on SQL SERVER 2012 to use the [`IIF`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213574.aspx) statement within the `SELECT` where the first argument is the boolean condition to check, the second argument is the value when the expression is true and the last argument is for false value, ie, `SELECT IIF(a.finding_id <> b.finding_id, 'some_column', 'Transfer Out')`

Comment: @AnthonyForloney, I posted answer in absence of your answer, post your comment as answer, I will delete mine.

Comment: @Rahul You're answer is sufficient for what the OP is looking for, so no need to delete it. Thanks

Comment: It looks like it's not possible to do IF statement in sql server. Case statement seems to do the trick. Thank you, All!!

Comment: `IF .. ELSE` construct is allowed only in a block level code like in procedure/func/trigger but in in normal ANSI SQL, NO; you will have to use `CASE` expression or `IIF` as already commented by @AnthonyForloney

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a `CASE` statement like below

```
select case when a.finding_id <> b.finding_id then some_column 
else 'Transfer Out' end as Calculated_column
from transfer_current_mc a 
inner join transfer_previous_mc b on a.finding_id = b.finding_id
```